# spring generic json response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring MVC` and returning `JSON` as response. I would like to create a generic `JSON` response where I can put in any TYPE and want the response to look like this

```
{
    status : "success",
    data : {
        "accounts" : [
            { "id" : 1, "title" : "saving", "sortcode" : "121212" },
            { "id" : 2, "title" : "current", "sortcode" : "445566" },
        ]
     }
}
```

So I created a `Response<T>` object

```
public class Response<T> {

    private String status;
    private String message;
    T data;
...
...
}
```

1. Is this the correct way of doing this, or is there a better way?.
2. How do you use this Response object in `Spring` controller to return an empty response object and/or a populated response object.

Thanks in advance GM

**UPDATE:**

In order to get the similar `JSON` output as the one described, i.e. with "accounts" key in `JSON`, I had to use `Response<Map<String, List<Account>>>` the following in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/accounts"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response<Map<String, List<Account>>> findAccounts(@RequestBody AccountsSearchRequest request) {
        //
        // empty accounts list
        //
        List<Account> accountsList = new ArrayList<Account>();

        //
        // response will hold a MAP with key="accounts" value="List<Account>
        //
        Response<Map<String, List<Account>>> response = ResponseUtil.createResponseWithData("accounts", accountsList);

        try {
            accountsList = searchService.findAccounts(request);

            response = ResponseUtil.createResponseWithData("accounts", accountsList);
            response.setStatus("success");
            response.setMessage("Number of accounts ("+accounts.size()+")");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus("error");
            response.setMessage("System error " + e.getMessage());
            response.setData(null);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Is this the right way of doing this? i.e. in order to get the "accounts" key in `JSON` output?

Comment: That's a useful common response entity.

Answer (score 3):

While your example JSON is not valid (`status` and `data` are not enclosed in quotations), this approach will work.

You will want to ensure that you have the Jackson jars on your classpath, and Spring will take care of the rest.

To get this to work, I would create a constructor for your response class that looks something like this:

```
public class Response<T> {

    private String status;
    private String message;
    private T data;

    public Response(String status, String message, T data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    //...getter methods here

}
```

And then in your Spring controller, you just return this object from your method that is mapped with `@RequestMapping`

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/mypath", produces="application/json")
    public Response<SomeObject> myPathMethod() {
        return new Response<SomeObject>("200", "success!", new SomeObject());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. Is this the correct way of getting the "accounts" key in JSON?

Comment: Remember to put `getters` and `setters`. Otherwise, response return empty object!

Comment: What if data is null, what should I use in Response<?>